# how to await for the aws cognito authenticateUser call (which appears to be a callback)

Tags: reactjs, callback, async-await, aws-amplify, amazon-cognito

So we are using await/async calls, but the authenticateUser command provided by aws-amplify appears to use a callback.  I am a python coder and have not coded with node in quite a while, so this may be a naive question!

I tried converting it to a promise like so:

```
function authenticateUserAsync(user, authDetails) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject, challenge) {
          user.authenticateUser(authDetails, { 
                          onSuccess: resolve,
                          onFailure: reject, 
                          newPasswordRequired: challenge });

    }).then(
        function(result) { 
           return result; 
        });
}
```

and later

```
 idToken = await authenticateUserAsync(user, authDetails,
    function(result) {
        console.log("Token: ");
        console.log(result.idToken);
        return result.idToken;
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({idToken: ''});
        if (err.code == 'NotAuthorizedException') {
                return 'not_authorized';
        } else {
                return 'unknown_error';
        }

    },
    function(userAttrs, reqAttrs) {
        return 'challenge';
    } 
  );
```

But, no matter how I tweak it, the code flows right on by and then I get an unhandled promise rejection (in my test the auth fails at the moment)

Answer (score 13):

Good on you for trying to implement a call to `authenticateUser()` with modern-day Javascript constructs, but there are several issues with your approach. I'd be really curious to see the finished code.

The main issue is that Cognito `authenticateUser()` needs three callbacks and promises only handle two. A dummy function can be passed for the `newPasswordRequired` callback, if you never expect to hit that code-path. Another approach is to use the `resolve` function for both the `onSuccess` and the `newPasswordRequired` callbacks.

A second issue is that your `authenticateUserAsync()` only takes two parameters. You are trying to pass some additional callbacks to it. Those callbacks are ignored. *That* is why it flows right on by and you get an unhandled promise exception. The unnecessary `.then()` doesn't help either.

My implementation ended up like this:

```js
function asyncAuthenticateUser(cognitoUser, cognitoAuthenticationDetails) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(cognitoAuthenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: resolve,
      onFailure: reject,
      newPasswordRequired: resolve
    })
  })
}

async signIn({ commit }, authData) {
  let cognitoUserPool = new CognitoUserPool(config.poolDetails)
  let cognitoAuthenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authData);
  let userData = { Username: authData.Username, Pool: cognitoUserPool }
  let cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData)

  try {
    let result =
      await asyncAuthenticateUser(cognitoUser, cognitoAuthenticationDetails)

    if ('idToken' in result) {
      console.log('We have a token:  ' + JSON.stringify(p));
    }
    else {
      console.log('We need a new password.')
      delete result.email_verified // Not accepted by the challenge call
      delete result.phone_number_verified // Also not accepted

      // Get a new password from the user then call
      // cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge()
    }
    catch (error) {
      // Probably a mis-typed password
      console.log(error.message)
    }
}
```

An alternative library to `amazon-cognito-identity-js`, which uses common ES6 concepts, like async/await would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

here is the right way to use asyc/await, you can not use `await` keyword alone , it should be inside a function with `async` keyword in function signature

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  try{
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  const data = await res.json()
   console.log(data)
  }catch(err){
     console.log('error from fetch : ',err)
  }
}

fetchData()
```

i think in your example you can do something like this

```js
const getIdToken = async () => {
  try{
  idToken = await authenticateUserAsync(user, authDetails,
    function(result) {
        console.log("Token: ");
        console.log(result.idToken);
        return result.idToken;
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({idToken: ''});
        if (err.code == 'NotAuthorizedException') {
                return 'not_authorized';
        } else {
                return 'unknown_error';
        }

    },
    function(userAttrs, reqAttrs) {
        return 'challenge';
    } 
  );
  return idToken;
  }catch(err){
     console.log('error from fetch : ',err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention my code snippet was inside an async function, a larger onSubmit handler - but I am trying your solution now, inside that

Comment: Yeah, thanks so much for the response, but somehow it still does not wait for the completion before going on to the next line, then I get 'possible unhandled promise rejection' - but maybe its that I'm getting an unexpected error that I'm not handling in the callback, rather than the await syntax itself.

Comment: Aha - I was getting an unhandled promise rejection from something else!  So the original code was probably fine, since it was already inside an async function - it was something else that was throwing that.  But I am upvoting the answer since it explains about having to be inside an async, thanks again

Comment: (and for some reason the console.log inside the success callback does not seem to be writing to the console, even though the success callback must have run since idToken is set to the real result.  so that also was confusing)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this question (from a fellow python-developer with some catch-up to do on recent node patterns).  Based on this SO and some other OSS sources, the following seems to work, given a suitable config file (see below).  This is intended to be a nodejs module (the solution will differ slightly in the browser).

```js
/* jshint esversion: 8 */
/* jshint node: true */

// The amazon-cognito-identity-js package assumes fetch is available in a web browser.  Since
// nodejs does not have fetch built-in it is emulated like this:
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require("amazon-cognito-identity-js");

function asyncCognitoAuthentication(cognitoConfig) {
  const cognitoUserPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: cognitoConfig.userPoolId,
    ClientId: cognitoConfig.clientId,
  });
  const cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser({
    Username: cognitoConfig.username,
    Pool: cognitoUserPool,
  });
  const authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(
    {
      Username: cognitoConfig.username,
      Password: cognitoConfig.password,
    }
  );

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: resolve,
      onFailure: reject,
      newPasswordRequired: resolve,
    });
  });
}

const cognitoJWT = {
  session: undefined,
  jwtAccess: undefined,
  jwtId: undefined,
  jwtRefresh: undefined,
  jwtPayloads: undefined,
};

module.exports.getCognitoJWT = async function (cognitoConfig) {
  try {
    const session = await asyncCognitoAuthentication(cognitoConfig);
    cognitoJWT.session = session;
    cognitoJWT.jwtAccess = session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
    cognitoJWT.jwtId = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
    cognitoJWT.jwtRefresh = session.getRefreshToken().getToken();
    cognitoJWT.jwtPayloads = {
      jwtAccess: session.getAccessToken().decodePayload(),
      jwtId: session.getIdToken().decodePayload(),
    };
    return cognitoJWT;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};

const process = require("process");
if (process.env.TEST_AUTH === "test") {
  const config = require("config");
  const cognitoConfig = config.get("cognito");
  console.log(cognitoConfig);

  Promise.resolve(module.exports.getCognitoJWT(cognitoConfig)).then(
    (cognitoJWT) => {
      console.log(cognitoJWT);
    }
  );
}
```

The `config` file is located in `./config/default.json`, with a structure like the following (substitute actual values into the `{}` fields):

```
{
    "logLevel": "info",
    "cognito": {
        "clientId": "{client-app-id}",
        "userPoolId": "{aws-coginto-pool-id}",
        "region": "{aws-region}",
        "username": "{your-username}",
        "password": "{your-password}"
    }
}
```

The `package.json` is like:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test-cognito-auth": "TEST_AUTH=test node ./cognito_auth.js"
  },
  "license": "Apache 2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^4.3.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.686.0",
    "config": "^3.3.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.0.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I have created a function and returned a promise like this: 

const myfunc = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
              onSuccess: resolve,
              onFailure: reject,
              newPasswordRequired: resolve,
            });
 });
}

and then called that function with await like this:

const result = await myfunc();
```